# Accessing generic container from abstract item-class in java

Tags: java, generics, subclass, super

I'm trying to implement a container which is generic about it's items. All possible item classes share a single abstract base class which provides access to the surrounding container.

The following code shows my simplest approach:

```
public class GenericContainerProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container<SpecificItem> container = new Container<>();
        new SpecificItem(container);
    }

    private static class Container<ItemType extends AbstractItem> {
        private final List<ItemType> list = new ArrayList<>();

        public Container() {
            //
        }

        protected void addItem(ItemType specificItem) {
            list.add(specificItem);
        }
    }

    private static abstract class AbstractItem {
        protected final Container<? extends AbstractItem> container;

        public AbstractItem(Container<? extends AbstractItem> container) {
            this.container = container;
            container.addItem(this); // fails *
        }
    }

    private static class SpecificItem extends AbstractItem {
        public SpecificItem(Container<SpecificItem> container) {
            super(container);
            container.addItem(this); // succeeds
        }
    }

}
```

*) Error: `The method addItem(capture#3-of ? extends GenericContainer.AbstractItem) in the type GenericContainer.Container<capture#3-of ? extends GenericContainer.AbstractItem> is not applicable for the arguments (GenericContainer.AbstractItem)`

This doesn't work as is because of the possible type mismatch allowed by the declaration `? extends AbstractItem`. I think I need some type constraints telling the compiler the `Container<?>`-type used within `AbstractItem` is valid for `this`.

How can I declare/call the `AbstractItem`-class (and its constructor) in a way that it can access the container which is generic about a specific sub-class?

Comment: You can't add anything except literal null to a `Container<? extends A>`. You'd need `Container<? super A>`.

Comment: This was meant to be a placeholder for whatever solution seems right. Just replacing it with `super` results in an error when calling `super(container);`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you need to make AbstractItem generic, in order to specify the type of the container it uses. You'd also need to use an unchecked cast in the AbstractItem constructor.

But are you really sure you want such a bidirectional association between the container and the containee? Perhaps you should rethink this design.

```
public class GenericContainerProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container<SpecificItem> container = new Container<>();
        new SpecificItem(container);
    }

    private static class Container<ItemType extends AbstractItem<ItemType>> {
        private final List<ItemType> list = new ArrayList<>();

        public Container() {
            //
        }

        protected void addItem(ItemType specificItem) {
            list.add(specificItem);
        }
    }

    private static abstract class AbstractItem<T extends AbstractItem<T>> {
        protected final Container<T> container;

        public AbstractItem(Container<T> container) {
            this.container = container;
            container.addItem((T) this);
        }
    }

    private static class SpecificItem extends AbstractItem<SpecificItem> {
        public SpecificItem(Container<SpecificItem> container) {
            super(container);
            container.addItem(this);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I know it's uncommon, but should be possible :) It's going to be used in context of SWT where this style is quite common. It eases up the usage and (in a way) prohibits attaching a child to multiple parents. It also allows to fill some `final` variables within the constructor based on the container.

Comment: This leaves us with `Type safety: Unchecked cast from AbstractItem<T> to T` which should be perfectly fine in this case. Adding a dynamic check using an `instanceof` isn't applicable due to type erasure. I think java lacks of a way to specify the own specific type - something like `This` which would solve the problem.